# The URL of the index.html file in my new Google bucket includes the google storage path

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I made a new bucket in google cloud. Set the access permissions for allusers to view, and uploaded the website folders and files.

The url www.sustainabledebtrecovery.com doesn't work in my browser, so I checked the address of index.html in google cloud, and it this:

https://storage.cloud.google.com/www.sustainabledebtrecovery.com/index.html

Can anybody please help me... How do I get www.sustainabledebtrecovery.com to work on its own?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The documentation to set up a static website on GCS is [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#index-page). It seems you've solved your issue as www.sustainabledebtrecovery.com looks to be working just fine.

Comment: Were you able to resolve your issue ?

Comment: Sadly no. I temporarily pointed the DNS back to the temporary hosting site while I try to work it out :(

Comment: Sadly no. I temporarily pointed the DNS back to the temporary hosting site while I try to work it out :(.  I followed the static site set up guidelines over and over all night but it didn’t work. I guess either I haven’t got the DNS setup correctly in google domains, e.g there is no mention of needing an A record, I set up the cname per the guidelines. Do I need an A record or anything else in the google domain DNS settings? All I have is a CNAME and the name servers set as google nameservers. The guidelines appear to be silent on this.

Comment: I can see the website when I am logged into google cloud, by clicking on the long URL I mentioned in the original question. How do I get www.sustainabledebtrecovery.com to point to that bucket URL location?

Comment: Anybody know what the google domain dns settings should be? if the domain is registered with google domains, and my site is google hosted and in a bucket at https://storage.cloud.google.com/www.sustainabledebtrecovery.com/index.html

Comment: You should follow this [documentation](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3290350?hl=en) on how to set up DNS records properly ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfHsT.png}) and have a look at this one on [how to set up static website on GCP buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website).

When you change back your CNAME records please check if they're working with those tools: [MX Toolbox](https://mxtoolbox.com/CnameLookup.aspx) and [DNS Checker](https://dnschecker.org/) to ensure they propagated properly.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow this [documentation](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3290350?hl=en) on how to set up DNS records properly ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfHsT.png%7D) in Google Domains and have a look at this one on [how to set up static website on GCP buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website).

But first make sure your CNAME record is pointing to the `c.storage.googleapis.com`.

Right now your DNS points to the other provider you mentioned:

```
    dig www.sustainabledebtrecovery.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.12-Ubuntu <<>> www.sustainabledebtrecovery.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 47899
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.sustainabledebtrecovery.com. IN    A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.sustainabledebtrecovery.com. 6181 IN CNAME  sustainabledebtrecovery.com.
sustainabledebtrecovery.com. 6225 IN    A       68.66.226.78
```

Proper configuration should look like this:

[image]

You don't need A record in this case.

When you change back your CNAME records please check with those tools: [MX Toolbox](https://mxtoolbox.com/CnameLookup.aspx) and [DNS Checker](https://dnschecker.org/) to ensure they propagated properly.

Next - make sure your bucket name matches your domain name - in your case `www.sustainabledebtrecovery.com`

Upload the files, [set the permissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#sharing_your_files) (at bucket level if you want the users to be able to access all files in it or object level to have more control over who can access what)

If everything is set up right your site should be working and accessible for everyone.